# @DateTimeFormat annotation not working in Spring Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-el

I am following Spring Documentation 4. Through its guidelines I successfully collected the correctly formatted Date field.
The Controller Class is

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView("page1", "myForm", new MyForm());
    }
}
```

MyForm Class has a field **date** annotated with **@DateTimeFormat**

```
public class MyForm{

    @NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
    private Double value = 50.00;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date date = new Date();

    @NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
    public Double getValue() {
    return value;
   }

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

The JSP code that takes this myForm object and evaluates **correctly formatted** value of **date** field is

```
<spring:eval expression="myForm.date"/>
```

This far everything is **correct**. But when I try to use the **date** field inside my **Spring Controller** class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date date;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    date = new Date();
    return new ModelAndView("page1", "date", getDate());
    }
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
```

}

The JSP code that takes this myForm object and evaluates **incorrectly formatted** value of **date** field is

```
<spring:eval expression="date"/>
```

It still displays the date but doesn't format it. Please explain why it formats a field in MyForm Class but not a field in Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POJO MyForm is populated by Spring framework itself while submitting the form. Spring takes request parameters, convert into correct format and populate fields of your empty POJO but if you call methods annotated by `@DateTimeFormat` manually then it doesn't work as expected.

You have to use java [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) or joda [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) in controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir, But MyForm is not being created and Populated by Spring Framework. I am creating it myself by a call to its constructor. Please look at the code. Initially the controller calls new MyForm(); in statement return new ModelAndView("page1", "myForm", new MyForm());

Comment: but you are not setting the fields in the form manually. It's populated by spring itself while sending the request to the controller. Think about a filter that inspect the request parameters and populates your empty POJO object just for you.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you Sir, but in MyForm, I added a date setter method and populated it myself from the controller, In that case too, it is working. The date field in POJO MyForm is being set manually and even then, it displays correct format. But when I set the date field present in Controller, then it doesn't work.

Comment: when spring changes the format? 1. POJO is send to client from server 2. Form is submitted but in case of Controller you are in same class at server side. Spring doesn't come into picture. It's all spring interceptors and filters that do the translation in the background of the request.

Comment: Thanks Sir. For helping me in clearing my doubts, And to learn that your name is Braj, an Indian, doubles my pleasure. - Ankit from Delhi